# ActionScript: Scan image for other images

Tags: actionscript-3, image-processing, flex4, image-recognition

I know this doesn't have a simple answer, but I want to learn how to scan images, and thus videos (frame-by-frame) and identify other images in that initial image with a given amount of error.

Are there any libraries for this? Any hints?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you refer to Augmented Reality (or AR, I don't really know if there's a more technical word for it). There are a few libraries out there, mostly [FLARToolKit](http://www.libspark.org/wiki/saqoosha/FLARToolKit/en), plus a few forks of it. This is mostly for recognizing markers or patterns within an image (or video).

I know @inspirit is doing some really cool stuff in this area and has been posting a lot in his [blog](http://blog.inspirit.ru/), but afaik he hasn't released anything yet.

Comment: Hi Cay, thank you for your answer. I am looking for more than AR, I am looking for image recognition like objects, faces etc.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean... you need a program that would say "in this image there's a tree, a painting, a tv screen and 2 faces", or "imageX is present in this image, faceY is not"?... The latter is quite possible. The first option is very hard (impossible?), as you would have to provide the program with some way of recognizing a tree, a tv, a face, etc... anyway, it's all very tricky and depends a lot of your specific requirements. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I have an image of an object. I want to match that image in another image. Track it in video etc. So basically image comparison. I don't want to tell it to find `a tree`, I want to give it an image of a tree and ask if it can find a match in another image.

Comment: Well, that's basically the gist of AR... have a look at @inspirit's videos http://blog.inspirit.ru/?p=444... oh, and look at that, he already released the SDK www.in2ar.com :)

Comment: Thanks, just saw your comment. I'll give that a read and come back.